# I encountered System.IndexOutOfRangeException when loading a txt file

Tags: c#, text, split, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying the load a txt file which is written under a certain format, then I have encountered System.IndexOutOfRangeException. Do you have any idea on what's wrong with my codes? Thank you!

txt.File:

```
P§Thomas§40899§2§§§
P§Damian§40726§1§§§
```

P=Person; Thomas=first name; 40899=ID; 2=status

here are my codes:

```
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                while (file.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    string line = file.ReadLine();

                    char[] charSeparators = new char[] { '§' };
                    string[] parts = line.Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    foreach (PersonId personids in PersonIdDetails)
                    {
                        personids.ChildrenVisualisation.Clear();

                        foreach (PersonId personidchildren in personids.Children)
                        {
                            personidchildren.FirstName = parts[1];
                            personidchildren.ID = parts[2];
                            personidchildren.Status = parts[3];

                            personids.ChildrenVisualisation.Add(personidchildren);
                        }
                    }                             
                }
            }
```

at parts[1] the exception was thrown.

Comment: Your file probably contains some empty lines, for which split will return an empty array.
You should add a check after readline: `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) continue;`

Comment: There is also a `File.ReadAllLines` static method that returns a `string[]`.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first `foreach` and you can view the parts array in Visual Studio. You can also add a line `Debug.Assert(parts.Length > 3);` right after the `Split` line.

Comment: I am agree with aegar and apart from that there is posibility that data is like P$$$$$$ b'coz you remove empty entries this

Comment: You can also visualize the result and check also the `Length` of your array before accessing by number as you do.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the comments, I will try one by one out! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm given the impression that the actual file is not that big, so it might be useful to use `File.ReadAllLines` instead (the con is the you need to have the entire file in memory), which gives you all the lines.

Also, removing the lines which are either empty or just whitespace might be necessary.

```
        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l))
        {
           char[] charSeparators = new char[] { '§' };
           string[] parts = line.Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

           foreach (PersonId personids in PersonIdDetails)
           {
             personids.ChildrenVisualisation.Clear();

             foreach (PersonId personidchildren in personids.Children)
             {
               personidchildren.FirstName = parts[1];
               personidchildren.ID = parts[2];
               personidchildren.Status = parts[3];
               personids.ChildrenVisualisation.Add(personidchildren);
             }
           }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check if `parts` have *enough items*:

```
  ...

  string[] parts = line.Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

  foreach (PersonId personids in PersonIdDetails) {
    personids.ChildrenVisualisation.Clear();

    // Check if parts have enough infirmation: at least 3 items
    if (parts.Length > 3) // <- Pay attention for "> 3"
      foreach (PersonId personidchildren in personids.Children) {
        //TODO: Check, do you really start with 1, not with 0?
        personidchildren.FirstName = parts[1];
        personidchildren.ID = parts[2];
        personidchildren.Status = parts[3];

        personids.ChildrenVisualisation.Add(personidchildren);
      }
    else {
      // parts doesn't have enough data
      //TODO: clear personidchildren or throw an exception 
    } 
  }   

  ...
```

Comment: @verdesrobert: That's why `parts.Length > 3` so parts.Length at least 4

Comment: It seemed to me like the other answer sorry

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line to
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(fileName, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")));

Comment: StreamReader without Encoding parameter does not recognize the character "§".

Comment: Did it work? Checking the length will help you to handle the exception. but that does not solve your problem, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Possible way  to do it, It's just one solution between more solutions

```
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            while (file.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                string line = file.ReadLine();

                char[] charSeparators = new char[] { '§' };
                string[] parts = line.Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                foreach (PersonId personids in PersonIdDetails)
                {
                    personids.ChildrenVisualisation.Clear();

                    foreach (PersonId personidchildren in personids.Children)
                    {
                       if(parts.Length > 3)//Only if you want to save lines with all parts but you can create an else clause for other lines with 1 or 2 parts depending on the length
                       {
                        personidchildren.FirstName = parts[1];
                        personidchildren.ID = parts[2];
                        personidchildren.Status = parts[3];

                        personids.ChildrenVisualisation.Add(personidchildren);
                       }
                    }
                }                             
            }
        }
```

Comment: The exception disappear after I add this. I thought after Split it should have 4 arrays automatically. Can you please explain this to me? =)

Comment: Yea, I put parts.Length>3 then it's ok.

Comment: @doubleo.cbh try to remove the 2 in the end and you will surely get an exception

Comment: @verdesrobert I once have a particular problem like this. the last part is `parts[3]` after [2],[1],[0]... which means 4 elements

Comment: but when the 4th part is missing it gives exception

Comment: Where does the exception originate from? Shouldn't the array be more than 3 everytime it's loaded?

Comment: You could just Edit the answer @verdesrobert by removing `=`.

Comment: i'm not allowed to only change one character that's up to you

Comment: No prob. @verdesrobert